# Using C++ with Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm figuring out that there's two ways of writing C++ in Eclipse: either download the [Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/galileosr1) or download the regular Eclipse for java and add the CDT plugin. What is the difference between these two? (Note that I'm already exstensively using Eclipse for Java) Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C++ tools end up the same so depends if you use Eclipse for other things.

If for other things then I would start with the more complex setup e.g. if you do Java J2EE I would download the [Eclipse J2EE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/galileo/SR1/eclipse-jee-galileo-SR1-macosx-cocoa.tar.gz) then add the C++ tools

If just C++ start with the Eclipse C++

I also found using the Yoxos/Eclipse Source packaging easier to download extra packages. (unless you need the absolute latest patch)

edit:
Sorry I did not read the question fully I have given the general answer. However as you have eclipse working and setup already and if you are happy then just download the C++ plugins. Note I have a separate workspace for java and C++ helps as you will want different perpecives etc and also cuts down on the projects in the explore rs/

Comment: The IDE for C++ contains the CDT, Mylyn, and the EPP usage data collector (http://www.eclipse.org/epp/usagedata/).  The regular "classic" eclipse has JDT & PDE which are absent from the C++ distro.

Comment: Also, the spellchecker doesn't work unless the Java Development tools are also installed or you fix it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48390/eclipse-spelling-engine-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 1):

Or use [EasyEclipse for C/C++](http://www.easyeclipse.org/site/distributions/cplusplus.html) and get a few other useful tools pre-integrated too.

Comment: EasyEclipse for C/C++ is a bit dated. The official Eclipse version should be used instead.